# sqlite query fails with "Error: no such column"

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have the following database:

```
lab-1:~# sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db "select * from users"
John|Doe|Test|0||1|1234|6988|sip
Jane|Doh|test|0||3|6878|123@abc.com|smtp
lab-1:~# sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db ".schema"
CREATE TABLE users(fname varchar(100), lname varchar(100), description varchar(100),grp INTEGER, group_name varchar(100), destination_id varchar(100), p_number varchar(10), destination varchar(100), class varchar(10));
```

**THIS WORKS**

The following query works no problem, via bash script

```
lab-2:/tmp# ssh root@lab1.mydomain.net "sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE destination='6981' AND p_number='9999''"                                                                                                                                       
0
lab-2:/tmp#
```

It correctly returns a count of 0.

**THIS FAILS**

But when try to query based on the fname field... it bombs, like this:

```
lab-2:/tmp# ssh root@lab1.mydomain.net "sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where fname='John''"
Error: no such column: John
```

Just wondering if you can see my typo / mistake.  Tried to play around with quotes vs. single quotes... and also tried to add "\" to escape the quotes around the select statement... but so far, I haven't figured it out.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

This is what I did to prove to myself I have matching quotes / that I'm not missing any quotes - I laid out my query like so:

```
"
    sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db 
        '
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where fname='
                                                    John
                                                   '
        '
"
```

Comment: You did count your quotes, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did.  And i just counted again but I don't see anything that's missing.  But then again, I've been looking at this so long, I might be missing something .

Comment: Putting another quote doesn't nest the quotes, it closes the previous one.

Comment: ok so can you explain why the first query works?  but not the second?  I don't see the difference.  Also I've updated my question to show how I've been trying to verify I have the right number of quotes

Comment: The first query works because numbers don't use quotes.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry, I don't mean to be thick but just to make sure we are on the same page here... when I say first query, I'm talking about the one that (now has) the heading "This works".  I think you're reading the first query where I just select everything.  That's not the one I'm referring to when I say "it works".  But i've added bolded headings now to help make it more clear.

Comment: I edited my comment. Please make sure you're looking at the latest revision.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164856/discussion-between-dot-and-ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to nest single quotes, but it doesn't work like that. In your first ("working") example, your shell sees five strings representing your query. These are:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE destination='
6981
' AND p_number='
9999
''
```

Since there are no spaces separating them, it mushes them all together into one argument that gets passed to sqlite:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE destination=6981 AND p_number=9999
```

This is perfectly valid. However, in your second example, the shell sees these three strings:

```
'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where fname='
John
''
```

When mushed together, these yield:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where fname=John
```

Since there aren't any quotes around `John`, sqlite assumes this is meant to be a column name and complains accordingly.

You'll need to find an appropriate way to escape the innermost quotes so that the they survive the shell and get passed into sqlite.

Comment: Yes, thanks for taking the time to explain.  I already posted my answer- figured out I had to escape.  but thanks again.  I was only ahead of you by 1 minute.  lol

Answer (score 0):

Changed the single quotes around the select statement to double quotes... and escaped them.

```
lab-1:/tmp# ssh root@lab1.mydomain.net "sqlite3 /etc/ppd/page.db \"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users where fname='John'\""
```